# Where to put application level beans in Spring MVC?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, configuration-files

Where to put application level beans in Spring MVC? Into `root-context.xml` or into `servlet-context.xml`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Beans declared in `root-context.xml` (*services*) are visible for beans in `servlet-context.xml` (*controllers*), but not the other way around. Therefore there can be a dependency from controllers to services, but the reverse dependency is forbidden by Spring.

That being said put MVC-independent code (services, DAOs, etc.) in main context and put web-only stuff in servlet context.

Comment: More over, the beans definied in the root application context, can be accessed from (web request) filters and can be shared by different dispatcher servlets.